# Is it possible to create WebSocket application along with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I don't have much idea about Spring framework so I am asking here. Is it possible/OK to create an Spring based WebSocket application inside a larger Spring MVC app?

All examples that I have seen create only the WebSocket part but no MVC.
So is it possible to do this? If yes can someone point me to some good example.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring supports websocket and you can build websocket application using Spring. Spring supports STOMP over websocket and you can configure it as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
      config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/");
      config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
     }

     @Override
     public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
      registry.addEndpoint("/greeting");;
     }  
}
```

Above configuration will defines message broker STOMP endpoint and websocket application endpoint.
Once this is done you can connect to websocket from browser. It requires stomp.js loaded.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/greeting');
```

There are other confgurations required too at your controller level as example shown here - [Spring Websocket Example](http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-websocket-integration-example)

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj, this I already know. What I want to ask is that, wether this websocket application can be created as a part of bigger spring MVC application and can they both be deployed on the same server.

Comment: Yes I think its possible but it completely depends on how you design the architecture of your app.You should consider looking [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327644/how-to-architecture-a-realtime-heavy-websockets-based-web-application)